# How to clear all but the first non-zero lane in neon?

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, neon

I have a mask in a uint32x4_t neon register. In this mask at least 1 of the 4 ints is set (e.g. 0xffffffff), however, I may have a case where there are more than one items set in the register. How can I ensure that only one is set?

in c pseudo code:

```
uint32x4_t clearmask(uint32x4_t m)
{
         if (m[0]) { m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = 0; }
    else if (m[1]) { m[2] = m[3] = 0; }
    else if (m[2]) { m[3] = 0; }
    return m;
}
```

Basically I want to clear all but one of the set lanes. Obvious [straightforward implementation in neon](https://godbolt.org/g/Ves9x6) could be:

```
uint32x4_t cleanmask(uint32x4_t m)
{
    uint32x4_t mx;
    mx = vdupq_lane_u32(vget_low_u32(vmvnq_u32(m)), 0);
    mx = vsetq_lane_u32(0xffffffff, mx, 0);
    m = vandq_u32(m, mx);

    mx = vdupq_lane_u32(vget_low_u32(vmvnq_u32(m)), 1);
    mx = vsetq_lane_u32(0xffffffff, mx, 1);
    m = vandq_u32(m, mx);

    mx = vdupq_lane_u32(vget_high_u32(vmvnq_u32(m)), 0);
    mx = vsetq_lane_u32(0xffffffff, mx, 2);
    m = vandq_u32(m, mx);

    return m;
}
```

How can this be done more efficiently in arm neon?

Comment: So you want to zero all but the first non-zero lane?  Are they always 0 / -1 (which you could use directly as an AND or AND-NOT mask), or are other non-zero values possible for the first or later elements?

Comment: Note that you can simplify your sample implementation to leave out zeroing elements that were already checked with `if()`.

Comment: yes, values are only `0` or `-1`, and I want to end up with a neon register that has only one of them set to -1 (doesn't necessarily have to be first one).

Comment: @PeterCordes clearmask simplified, and added matching neon impl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Very simple](https://godbolt.org/g/xHWJw4):

```
vceq.u32    q1, q0, #0
vmov.i8     d7, #0xff
vext.8      q2, q3, q1, #12

vand        q0, q0, q2
vand        d1, d1, d2
vand        d1, d1, d4
```

6 instructions total, 5 if you can keep q3 as a constant.

The `aarch64` version below must be easier to understand:

```
cmeq    v1.4s, v0.4s, #0
movi    v31.16b, #0xff

ext     v2.16b, v31.16b, v1.16b, #12
ext     v3.16b, v31.16b, v1.16b, #8
ext     v4.16b, v31.16b, v1.16b, #4

and     v0.16b, v0.16b, v2.16b
and     v0.16b, v0.16b, v3.16b
and     v0.16b, v0.16b, v4.16b
```

---

### How this works

[`ext`/`vext`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489f/CIHGAEFI.html) takes a window from the concatenation of two vectors, so we're creating masks

```
v0 = [  d   c   b   a ]

v2 = [ !c  !b  !a  -1 ]
v3 = [ !b  !a  -1  -1 ]
v4 = [ !a  -1  -1  -1 ]
```

The highest element (`d`) is zeroed if any of the previous elements are non-zero.

The 2nd highest element (`c`) is zeroed if any of its preceding elements (`a` or `b`) are non-zero.  And so on.

---

With elements guaranteed to 0 or -1, `mvn` also works instead of a compare against zero.

Comment: Can you please explain what's happening there? Also, what's the output? I assume it has to be `q0`, but then last two `vand` instructions seem to be pointless as they don't touch `q0`.

Comment: @Pavel d1 is the upper part of q0. And yes, q0 is both input and output.

Comment: I'll add the `aarch64` version. That should be easier to understand, albeit longer and less efficient.

Comment: This works perfectly. I'd need to draw on paper to see what's going on, but it does work :) By the way, neon intrisic version seem to [produce better results](https://godbolt.org/g/xHWJw4) for arm64: produces same number of instructions, but it uses less registers (doesn't touch `v4` and `v31`)

Comment: By the way, I know you do not favor intrinsics, but I've seen in my tests where complex large functions produce extremely bad asm overloaded with register spills, and the same function coded manually to avoid spills... and the bad compiler generated function runs like 15-25% faster. I tested clang, armcc and gcc with different optimization options and cpu settings and gcc version was the best.

Comment: @Pavel It only means that your assembly skills lack. You could post one, and I'd tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, that my asm skill are far from optimal, at work I do something else, this is my hobby at spare time ;)

Comment: @Pavel What's so difficult in assembly is the limited number of registers that you have to manage manually. Writing NEON codes in assembly on the other hand is a real cakewalk since you have a really healthy number of registers, especially on `aarch64`. YUV to RGB conversion in pure assembly would be a headache even for me, but a trivial thing with NEON.

Comment: Yes, yuv2rgb is a solved problem for neon. libyuv does it  perfectly fine. Regarding that sample code that is much faster even though it's bigger and overloaded with register spills. These [are the two functions](https://www.pastiebin.com/5b423e4c97928). This is the impl of the findDissimilar from my other question (I described implimintation approach in my own reply there), second function is larger, overloaded with spills and ... runs 20+% faster on iPhone6.

Comment: @Pavel There are way too many junk opensource NEON codes on the web. I prefer writing my own. I might check libyuv though.

Comment: `libyuv` runs on every mobile phone basically. It's by google, I've done some contributions/fixes there at some point. It could be done a bit better, but for flexibility it provides it's by far fastest rgb/yuv conversion lib available IMO. Also, it has neon, sse and other optimizations and supports many typical yuv formats (like nv12 and others).

Comment: @Pavel From Google? Well, from what I've seen in AOSP so far, their NEON codes absolutely suck. I could teach some college freshmen for two weeks, they would write better NEON codes than Google. I'm not kidding.

Comment: Google is tens of thousands of people, and probably less than 100 know neon, and probably 10 of them are very good at it; still even some perf critical code won't probably be done by them, but the people who own the code. yuv/rgb conversion isn't that complex to get it done right. pixman is another lib that has yuv/rgb conversion and I think it has contributions from some of the best neon coders (Mans R., Siarhei S.), yet libyuv by far performs better in my tests.

Comment: So, if anything is done by google it doesn't mean it has the same quality/result across projects. You should review individual projects. Take a look at [neon for yuv conversion](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/master/source/row_neon.cc)

Comment: @Pavel Yes, it still sucks. Not as bad as what they did in SKIA, but it's a sub-par implementation nevertheless.

Comment: What specifically do you think makes it suck? I cannot find anything for yuv in skia, just random peices here and there, not much code, just some refs from other third party libs.

Comment: 1. I cannot imagine why someone would need `vmovl` for YUV conversions; 2. The instruction scheduling is bad; 3. It's written in inline assembly.

Comment: You can always send them patches or suggestions on how to improve. It's mostly maintained by a single guy at google. I never tried to deeply understand their asm, but from my experience long time ago when I did video calls for mobiles it produced by far better results than anything else. Also, that code is made not only to convert between different yuv flavors to different rgb flavors, it also does scaling at the same time. Basically typical scenario for a video call: convert and resize, you do it all in one call and it does it very well.

Comment: @Pavel I'm not a big fan of opensource. They provide sub-par performing codes for free which makes monetizing on top-notch products difficult. Just look at the compiler market. There is no competition at all because of GCC and Clang. I'd rather pay a few hundred bucks for a decent compiler than wasting my time on configuring lackluster toolchains.

Comment: Nice algorithm, I knew my answer seemed clunky but I didn't see this logic right away.  Added an explanation of the logic.  (I had to look up some ARM instructions to find out what they did to see what masks you were creating.)   BTW, an x86 version of this could do the same thing with `palignr`, which is exactly like `vext.8`.

Answer (score 1):

I had nearly the same idea as your uncommented code: broadcast inverted elements as an AND mask to zero later elements if that one is set, otherwise leave the vector unmodified.

**But if you're using this in a loop and have 3 spare vector registers, you can NOT all but one element with XOR, instead of MVN + set one element.**

`vdupq_lane_u32(vget_low_u32(m), 1);` appears to compile efficiently as a `vdup.32 q9, d16[1]`, and that part of my code is the same as yours (but without the mvn).

Unfortunately this is a long serial dependency chain; we're creating the next mask from the AND result, so there's no ILP.  I don't see a good way to make this lower latency while still getting the desired result.

```
uint32x4_t cleanmask_xor(uint32x4_t m)
{
    //                 {  a    b    c   d }
    uint32x4_t maska = {  0, ~0U, ~0U, ~0U};
    uint32x4_t maskb = {~0U,   0, ~0U, ~0U};
    uint32x4_t maskc = {~0U, ~0U,   0, ~0U};

    uint32x4_t tmp = vdupq_lane_u32(vget_low_u32(m), 0);
    uint32x4_t aflip = tmp ^ maska;
    m &= aflip;  // if a was non-zero, the rest are zero

    tmp = vdupq_lane_u32(vget_low_u32(m), 1);
    uint32x4_t bflip = tmp ^ maskb;
    m &= bflip;  // if b was non-zero, the rest are zero

    tmp = vdupq_lane_u32(vget_high_u32(m), 0);
    uint32x4_t cflip = tmp ^ maskc;
    m &= cflip;  // if b was non-zero, the rest are zero

    return m;
}
```

([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwk2IBbAPotMqFgDoEG7BwAMAQRu2RCgrK4APACz6CqpZla6TIIA1hBOLC7uXj66AJQOHADsfHaqaarhkZ7eqrpuGim26blu6rIAIqoAbugiAA4AjvrMRvoirhBVwJgEzagA7m0dVbpVLE3tXBBxsaSq1vGyhcV5ZZVVgj1NLZhDU9ZuAGbHJ8dzeXMLBQ4ra9Ws6BMduudui4U36asa67WNzaxdpNOt1egwBntOqNxpCZnNaO9PmlvhVqpsCNtAZCDqdTq94YjUl87lUHk8pi8SoT7ETkaUftU/pjWsCuj19Ag8MAEJCRmNydNYrN5tSVvTURstgCWR0cbiziU5lxRcSGaSWI9Ya9qUjVMQemIWLlrnYkuUEnYAPQAKlUWEEXKNLFQBEwgk%2BHAArDxVEx0gAjdLIdLodSe81Er0%2Bv2qAB%2BMfjaUTXsqFvsXAAbCAo770tY8wWUw4SDn82lA2lg2lQ0XTabUTnMOlDulgOkEGla0Uwz7Yy3VP24/2%2B2HKqpLZbVM6fP65v7MMgmCJNgPfKxVPPVAAvTDEVCqfoITBGwN4QQsMBSAhphk5vDpKjpYLpBijtPWy03uyZVzZHx%2BAIgmCfQ3BIMJnF/aJcniU1kgSLh5BbWhdQnXwWjbdFBAyOpVAII9fXQdB9UELDUBbfxkA7NAWEEAhWB8TY6h0JhXQYABPFDJ2KbiePUZI0hjctiirO0%2BIjbs0h/KIckCEI/Vvfj5jmWNrAAVWUtSNNUs0TQkjIIOkmIgMDBSeBU9S8y0rSdKWXUpL/XIgODUzzKsyy4zUmyPgQzAGE2XVaJYvBg2o2j9IiVwZOMkRDijFM7l1Tt%2BIAWloCzUos6w5gy7K0ty7TEnNWzaXHScRBYJgGEdTBQ3BJh0EEUxONUEhVDq0MTCbfhVEEBAYsOBhMA0AAxeDZGPfBYrrPT7KgghdBwtUmWlIFhlBPpBmBOJLhVSSDIcpgBrwRbUXmxbPWwRy5N025uAzBlDqquoCjSVC8BbP1%2BiCKcTGSnc9zmPCm2InwdCbf7UDTYozpJZadl5dbwU255hQRG70lmnJ/SOk7Khhr1Ltk4J/XR5F1EzBlsael7StUd6NwPb7nRYP7d1QQH8JB319W3NmofSfGJThrFWXWzluVhYUrmKmb9qg5AcbufGLqu4JOBl26KdRBXqaWV7J3pwMvqw5nWYB3DObdUGeYh/m0n1AhDWNGWdLsKRZgYaRPSkUgWGkawfdQaRNH4brhDECRydkWgfYIf33dmYIQFkWRTGsawuFoABOWhM1ofOs4ADg8RhpA8H2/akAPSCDqQfcEEAsrjqv3dIOBYBgRAUFQBa8EGsgKAgNBe/7lB0O8YhyuCUhDj711iAbiB/Xj0h/QUHQ2OkGPSGH3RjwIAB5Fh2JXrBAjYQbT7wfVkAIPAqjdFfMDcBcRFdLefecXyV4IYg8F0D%2BHtWDsFDrwRgeB/QN1gBVPeIA3AOl0OgUgD9iAgF/lPIUNc6h3xMA3KQyUD6yFUMlWi6AficF4PwfOxC6LEFBNzXQGZy5CFEOISQCJS5SG9r7Fetc3CFwzMlJhaFgGqAgOglgwRYhiNwIQVqch6CqE0D3OofddxRwREo0BPBY7x0wUnWQiRTCek4cwgBnosqV2rrXeujdSDNwDrMduXdh6qP7uQSgri1GoKUMAieU8Z5z13IvZeLdV7r2IJvKQ29d77yPifMJZ9gGX0SdfBcd8H54Ors/V%2B79omfwiN/MJv9/6AMYMAlA2jwGQPgLMVA2C8C4OkAQohJCCBkIqBQvgvBqHJVofQnQoxEh%2BmSroZAdQRDkJIK6NwyUmCF2IboQ4EyfhGBMIsgaqAWJzLXj8BAOhQyjLwiIXQ/p66sIkHQD2XsK68OkPwwRwjfFsDERIqRMj8BEGIBouYyiR7qLkMqLRlDeC6Jbpgo89VdyUGuVIMxIALE8LCTYoQdiHEJ1IAY1OGYmEeESJ6Dw1hPQEozMXThshbnIukGCxxbdO4QCQF49xg8mXQsGcADMsgsqzwYPPEJK814VUiR/HePc94RHiVE6uSSL6SFSTfDJj8wk5OQG/OV28v6e2KX/AB%2BSgFsEqSCgQVUamQDqQ0pp%2BCD5cEWeMyZnTpnPzmQs0Zyz7XlDWUaV1dUCA7LwHsg5izjmnPORHdhsLuFWMDtIWwAAlAAsqoYAyBgwZlMKnfMEAqosBEG8D5cjvkKN%2BSo7xUdZDSJDkamlGKsXppTvWhtDaMymMpdY6lqKm56NhVwVt0a672K7cg4JjS/YeCAA%3D))

```
/* design notes
  [ a   b   c   d ]
  [ a  ~a  ~a  ~a ] 

&:[ a   0   0   0 ]
or[ 0   b   c   d ]

= [ e   f   g   h  ]
  [ ~f  f   ~f  ~f ]  // not b, because f can be zero when b isn't

= [ i   j   k   l ]
  ...
*/
```

With the loads hoisted out of a loop, this is only 9 instructions vs. 12, because we skip the `vmov.32 d1[0], r3` or whatever to insert a `-1` in each mask.  (**ANDing an element with itself is equivalent to ANDing with `-1U`**.)  `veor` with all-ones in the other elements replaces `vmvn`.

clang seems to be inefficient at loading multiple vector constants: it sets up each address separately instead of just storing them near each other where it can reach from one base pointer.  So you might want to consider alternate strategies for creating the 3 constants.

```
#if 1
    // clang sets up the address of each constant separately
    //                 {  a    b    c   d }
    uint32x4_t maska = {  0, ~0U, ~0U, ~0U};
    uint32x4_t maskb = {~0U,   0, ~0U, ~0U};
    uint32x4_t maskc = {~0U, ~0U,   0, ~0U};
#else
    static const uint32_t maskbuf[] = 
      { -1U, -1U, 0, -1U, -1U, -1U};
    // unaligned loads.
    // or load one + shuffle?
#endif
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce better code than naive impl that I posted. Check out solution by Jake, not sure how it works, but it produces twice less opcodes.

Comment: @Pavel: Are you looking at the stand-alone version that include loading the constants?  My answer explains that it's only good if it can inline into a loop and hoist the constant setup out of the loop; that should be obvious from the asm.  Jake's implementation is better, though.

Comment: Yes, this is a one-time thing that I need to do at the end of my function. I could possibly do this part in arm, but I'd need to move to arm, and then move back to neon and I was trying to make it better in neon by clearing the mask.